# Should the post "Bitcoin Exchange with Joomla" have been migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration

Should this post https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/534/bitcoin-exchange-with-joomla have been migrated?

The post in question

> How to setup Joomla in such way, to get bitcoin exchange.
>
> I'm talking about exchange for alt-coins, for bitcoin vs other
>   alt-coins.
>
> Is there complete plugins set?

It's not a particularly good question, but it is (I believe) on topic. Probably more so than Bitcoin SE, because of the reference to plugins. What do think?

Comment: I would have voted to delete it as a bad question. But if Bitcoin SE can help, it's better. Otherwise they will delete it as bad question :-)

Comment: It seems they already pointed out a similar question.

Comment: I had pretty much the same reaction: "It's not a particularly good question, but it is (I believe) on topic. Probably more so than Bitcoin SE, because of the reference to plugins." I think it is more on topic here, because no one at Bitcoin Exchange will likely discuss the plugin issue. Either way, I think it is mostly just a poor question that can't be answered, so I would rather close it than push the bad question around to other sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for opening up the discussion. This community is more about self moderation than a moderator imposing own opinions.

My thinking was:

- the question shows rather little knowledge of Joomla
- there has been little research being done.
- seems to be more bitcoin specific than Joomla (even though it was asking for a software recommendation for Joomla).

My first idea was to put it on hold, but reviewing the [Help from bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) decided to move it.

> **What topics can I ask about here?**
>
> the open-source Bitcoin client or other Bitcoin software

Comment: Thanks for giving the reasoning behind the migration. I can see the sense in migrating it, but I think I'd still leave it. My reason for that is that it gives them the chance to edit or rewrite it into something more suitable. If it does get closed (as it likely would have), we could leave a recommendation that the question might have better luck on another specific SE, but that it would be in their best interests to put more effort into their post (or something to that effect).